# AVPlayer get error (Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647) but only from lock screen, from app this working without issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

This happens time-to-time and on the different devices. The same iphone 6s with the same ios and in one device it works correct, but another no

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[session setActive: YES error: nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [DATA_MANAGER tmpPathToDecryptedAudio:unit];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error: &error];
self.player = player;
[self.player play];
```

Comment: Please provide some more context to the question.

Comment: AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [session setActive: YES error: nil];
    
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [DATA_MANAGER tmpPathToDecryptedAudio:unit];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error: &error];
  self.player = player;
 [self.player play];

Comment: this bug happens when i quickly tap play next or play previous several times in a row

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing call to **prepareToPlay**. You can try this

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:FILE_PATH]];
NSError *error;

AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];
if(error) {
 NSLog(@"Audio Player error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
 return;
}
audioPlayer.delegate = self;       
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                             withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                                   error:nil];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't forget this. I thought it happens because file does not have time for decrypt correct, but not. If I damaged file specially the same error appearance but  player can load next file, if I get this error for not damaged file player does not work anymore. If I open 
If I open app and then press next button player starts work